# Using glfw and glew

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I have problem understanding some opengl stuff using GLFW and GLEW.

i have 3 files shown below:

main.cpp:

```
#include "gamewindow.h"

int main() {

GameWindow *gameWindow = new GameWindow(1024, 768, "FirstOpenGLGame");

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (gameWindow->getRunning()) {
    /* Render here */

    gameWindow->render();
    gameWindow->update();

    gameWindow->setRunning();
}

delete gameWindow;

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

This is where the problem is, gamewindow.cpp:

```
#include "gamewindow.h"

GameWindow::GameWindow(int width, int height, const char* title) : _running(true),     _height(1024), _width(1024 * (16/9))
{
/* Initialize the library */

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
if(!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(0);
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if(!glewInit()){        // <-- problem is this
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

coordSettings();
}

void GameWindow::setRunning() {
_running = !glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
}

bool GameWindow::getRunning() {
return _running;
}

void GameWindow::render() {

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2d(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2d(100.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2d(100.0f, 800.0f);
glVertex2d(0.0f, 800.0f);
glEnd();

glfwSwapBuffers(window);

/* Poll for and process events */
glfwPollEvents();
}

void GameWindow::update() {

}

void GameWindow::coordSettings() {
glViewport( 0, 0, _width, _height );
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(0.0, _width, 0.0, _height, 0.0, -1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

and last the header file gamewindow.h:

```
#ifndef GAMEWINDOW_H
#define GAMEWINDOW_H

#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class GameWindow
{
private:
GLFWwindow* window;
bool _running;
GLfloat _width;
GLfloat _height;

void coordSettings();

public:
GameWindow(int width, int height, const char* title);

void setRunning();
bool getRunning();

void render();
void update();
};

#endif // GAMEWINDOW_H
```

everything works fine, but then i try to call glewInit() (without really understanding is i need to, or when i need to) but then nothing works. the program starts, but there is no window with a quad in it, like before. why is this? how is GLEW even used, and do i need it?

Comment: If you're not sure you need it - then you don't. The same is true for every other software library.

Comment: [Test the return value of `glewInit()` against `GLEW_OK`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html).

Comment: Try adding the line `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` prior to the `glewInit` call.

Comment: I've tried that, it just seems like the application shuts down immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

Test the return value of glewInit() against GLEW_OK as stated by genpfault.
Since the return value of glewInit is an GLenum specifying if there is an error or if its successful.

You can print the errors using this:

```
GLenum glewState = glewInit();
if(glewState != GLEW_OK){
    std::cout << "Error with glew: " << glewGetErrorString(glewState) << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

It's also necessary for windows depending on your versions to create an VAO buffer to draw anything on screen.